# react-native : How to remove vertical spacing in <Text>

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile-development, react-native-stylesheet

In react native default  when I use some large fontsize I got vertical spacing. I tried `lineHeight` but after giving exact lineHeight equals to fontSize it just remove spacing from top not from bottom. I have added the border to see the diff.

```
<Text 
    style={{
            fontSize: 40,
            lineHeight: 40, 
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
            borderWidth: 1
    }}
>
      Account
</Text>
```

I want to add some fix margin from top and bottom but that extra space added up and making more gap between elements. and I don't know how much this spacing is so I can add/sub it from original margin.

Note: I am just doing it for android now.

[image]

Comment: Remove the lineHeight is not an option?, because that prop gives you the space that you say

Comment: @enzou I tried it as well but it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1):

```
<Text
    style={{
      fontSize: 40,
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
      borderWidth: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      textAlign: 'center',
      margin: 50,
      alignSelf: 'flex-start'
    }}
  >
    Account
  </Text>
```

I think you need output like this

[image]

Comment: No, I need to remove that vertical spacing between text and border

Comment: @AfzalAli I edited my answer please check now

Comment: @Hetail  I think you didn't understand the question. I just want to remove vertical spacing not horizontal. Neither I wan't to position Text anywhere like you did justifiyContent center etc.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, the vertical spacing is set by the line height (there is no margin or padding).

Set the line height to 0.

Removing the line height declaration does not remove the line height, it implicitly sets it to a default value.